# MongoDB: How to update a compound item of an array ensuring no duplicates

Tags: mongodb

Here below is a hypothetical `Users` collection where more than one address is allowed:

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Grey",
  ...
  "addresses":
  [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "street": "..."
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "Home",
      "street": "..."
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "Office",
      "street": "..."
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Every address has a name... which should be unique – e.g. there couldn't be two addresses named *Default*. If I want to update let's say the address at index 1 (*Home*), how do I ensure the update data does not contain names *Default* and *Office*?

I guess a two-steps approach (i.e. `find` and then `update`) wouldn't be very correct since data might be updated between the `find` and the subsequent `update` operation, isn't?

Comment: which attribute you want to update on index 1 or you want to replace index 1 with new json.

Comment: I want to update the name attribute... and the new name *MUST* be different than the name of nay other address in the array (indexes 0 and 2 in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var renamed = 'Office'; // from user input
var users = getUserMongoCollection();    

users.update({_id:userId, 'addresses.name': { $ne : renamed } },
    { $set : { 'addresses.1.name' : renamed } }, function(err){
        //all done!
    });
```

Find the record by ID, and only update it if the array doesn't contain the new name.