# MongoDB: How to update a complex item of an array with a new complex item

Tags: mongodb

Here below is once again my hypothetical Users collection where more than one address is allowed:

```
{
  "firstName": "Joe",
  "lastName": "Grey",
  ...
  "addresses":
  [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Home",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Office",
      "street": "...",
      ...,
      "isDefault": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's suppose I want to update the second address (`Home`) with the following new item:

```
   {
      "name": "New home",
      "street": "Ruta del Sol"
    },
```

How do I update the second item of the array with the new item, also considering that the new item might or might not provide all the fields of an address?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205756/mongodb-how-to-update-a-compound-item-of-an-array-ensuring-no-duplicates/22207162?noredirect=1#22207162) Will shown me how to update a field at a given index, ensuring the address name remains unique. Now, instead of updating a single field, I want to update an entire item.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I've just updated my post. Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is transform new json data for update . Example:

Let us assume you have new Json data with only two fields 'name' and 'isDefault' .

```
var newData = {"name" : "New Val","isDefault":true};
var updateData = {};
for (key in newData ) {
      updateData["addresses.$."+key]=newData[key]; 
};
db.projectPlan.update({_id:1, 'addresses.name': 'Home'}, {$set:updateData});
```

Comment: I think what you suggest has the same problem as the solution suggested by Will... The fields not specified in "newData" are just lost.

Comment: i have update my answer , it was having one mistake . In for loop it has to iterate newData ,previously it was updateData. Just tested  it worked fine for me .@j3d

Comment: Unfortunately for me it doesn't: "{"$set":{"name":"default","zip":"9999"}}" drops all the other fields (e.g. city, country, etc.).

Comment: are you using for loop ?@j3d

Comment: why you are doing {"$set":{"name":"default","zip":"9999"}}" it has to constructed dynamically using for loop @j3d

Comment: my code is a bit different (I use Play/Scala)... so maybe my translation is not correct. What result do you expect from your loop? Is it not "{"$set":{"name":"default","zip":"9999"}}"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49172/discussion-between-sumeet-and-j3d)

Comment: The basic fundamental is that you have to dynamically form $set data from new Data set .If you have only two fields to update ,you have to dynamically form $set :{ "addresses.$.name" : "default", "addresses.$.zip" : '9999'} . @j3d

Answer (score 0):

```
var renamed = 'Office'; // from user input
var users = getUserMongoCollection();    

var address = {
 name: "Office,
 street: "Ruta del Sol"
};

users.update({_id:userId },
    { $set : { 'addresses.1' : address } }, function(err){
        //all done!
    });
```

Comment: I think question is for dynamic update . ? Any field can be updated , cant use position in this case @Will Shaver